# Prevent dirty read/write when updating shared file from alarm handler

Tags: python

I have a requirement where my process needs to periodically update a file (say every 5 seconds). This file is also being updated multiple times in normal code flow.

I am using python alarm to interrupt and periodically update this shared file. I am facing an issue of dirty read with this, which messes the content of my file.

Example code:

```
import signal
import time
import json

class AlarmException(Exception):
    pass

def alarmHandler(signum, frame):
    numbers = read()
    numbers["4"] = "Four"
    write(numbers)
    print(read())
    
def write(content):
    file = open("text.txt", "w")
    file.write(json.dumps(content))
    file.flush()
    
def read():
    file = open("text.txt", "r")
    return(json.load(file))

def dirtyread(timeout=5):
    # Alarm setup, call alarmHandler after 5 seconds
    signal.signal(signal.SIGALRM, alarmHandler)
    signal.alarm(timeout)
    
    # Initialize file
    numbers = {"1": "one", "2": "two"}
    write(numbers)
    
    # Read the file content 
    new_numbers = read()
    
    # Some processing after reading the file content
    time.sleep(7)
    
    # Write new content
    new_numbers["3"] = "Three"
    write(new_numbers)
    print(read())
    
    
dirtyread()
```

Output:

> {'1': 'one', '2': 'two', '4': 'Four'}
>
> {'1': 'one', '2': 'two', '3': 'Three'}

How can I prevent this from happening? That is want to see {'1': 'one', '2': 'two', '3': 'Three', '4': 'Four'} in my file. How can I use locking effectively to solve this problem?

Comment: You need to lock the file before writing to it

Comment: @hek2mgl Locking before writing won't solve, can you please read the code.

Comment: You should add a print statement in both read and write functions for debugging to see what's actually read/written and in which order. That should make more clear to you what happens

Comment: @hek2mgl I understand the code, I have only written it :), I am asking how can I prevent it. 

Taking a lock before writing won't help because as soon as I flush lock will be released.

Comment: Also, I can not keep the file locked once read operation is completed. You mean to say read, processing and write should happen under lock?

Comment: please put a print statement in both the read and write functions, update your question and say what is unclear. The code is reading the same values which it writes to the file.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198408/discussion-between-lokesh-agrawal-and-hek2mgl).